# angular-material2, the dataBase of md-table example is equal with dataService?

Tags: angular-material2

here is the example of official

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/table-http/table-http-example.ts

there is a class named `ExampleHttpDao`?

Is it equal with the dataService?

Can I use dataService replace it, like a BookService ?

I am confused why use `dataBase`(`ExampleHttpDao`) rather than a `dataService`?

And the `dataSource`, can I just return an `Observable` of `dataSerivce` within `ngOnInit` of Component?

Comment: Yes you can return `Observable` of dataSerivce within `ngOnInit` of component. Check out the plunker from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45394504/5556177). There's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular-material2/10911/md-table/32666/connect-datasource-from-external-api#t=20170807122016502311) in the docs too.

Comment: `ExampleHttpDao` is just a class name that they are using in the example. This is where data gets populated/retrieved from API. So, if you want to name it `DataService` for clarity, you can. This `ExampleHttpDao` (aka DataService) is then used in `ExampleDataSource` class to feed data to table.