# Using ConnectableObservable instead of DataSource in mat table

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

From what I understand mat table [dataSource](https://material.angular.io/guide/cdk-table#connecting-the-table-to-a-data-source) is a thin wrapper around an Observable and its interface looks a lot like the [ConnectableObservable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators).

After a bit of digging I realised that rxjs/ConnectableObservable's connect method returns either a [Disposable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) or a more likely 
 a [Subscription](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts) depending which source you trust. This doesn't quite match with the expected API from material.

The examples given on the material website do declare additional classes for some obscure reason however it feels like a regular ConnectableObservable should work just fine here.

Is there a way to make material table accept a ConnectableObservable as dataSource or is there a good reason why I should be extending the cdk/DataSource abstract class?

Here are two mildly related SO:

- [How to use material2 data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004524/how-to-use-material2-data-table)
- [How do I connect my md-table (cdk data-table) to a service to be used as the data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392622/how-do-i-connect-my-md-table-cdk-data-table-to-a-service-to-be-used-as-the-dat)

**ps** if you have a link to a working plunker/fiddle/whatever i'll be happy to provide an example

Comment: From the look of the datasource example code you provided, i think it expect a connect method which return a Observable for component to subscribe for data. I guess internally it get's its data like this.datasource.connect().subscribe((res)=>this.row=res). 

ConnectableObservable connect method does a totally different thing, so i think you can't replace the formal abstract implementation with that.

Comment: @FanCheung is right, DataSource is not a thin wrapper around ConnectableObservable, it is an entirely different abstraction that just happens to also have a method named `connect()`

Comment: @FanCheung why not write an answer to this so I can close? I can't accept a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source code of md table stating it expect connect to return a behaviorSubject
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/table-data-source.ts

```
export class MatTableDataSource<T> implements DataSource<T> {

 /** Stream emitting render data to the table (depends on ordered data 
     changes). */
  private _renderData = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);

/**
  * Used by the MatTable. Called when it connects to the data source.
  * @docs-private
  */
 connect() { return this._renderData; }
.
.
.
```